# Mysql version 8.0 not authenticating using Java due to New Default Authentication Plugin : caching_sha2_password

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection

I'm trying to connect new version of MYSQL 8.0 using Java with the below code.

```
public static void checkMySqlConnection() throws Exception{
    String url = String.format("jdbc:mysql://%s:%s/%s?user=%s&password=%s","localhost", "3306", "test","user", "password");
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection  connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        System.out.println("Connection Successful");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

but it fails due to New Default Authentication Plugin **caching_sha2_password**

one solution is to create a user with **Native Authentication** , but I want to connect using **new** Authentication plugin.

Thank you for support in advance.

[Changes Affecting MYSQL 8.0](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#upgrade-caching-sha2-password-compatible-connectors)

Comment: You need to use MySQL Connector/J 5.1.46 or higher.

Comment: I Have upgraded to connector to 8.0.11 but still getting error. do I need to sha256 my password also?

Comment: Could you update your question with the full exception stacktrace you get when using MySQL Connector/J 8.0.11.